# Homotopy groups of the boundary of a projectively or conformally compactified hyperbolic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, manifolds-with-boundary

Say that we have a projectively or conformally compactified hyperbolic manifold, and we know the homotopy groups (so just the fundamental group) of the hyperbolic manifold. Can we say anything about the homotopy groups of the boundary?

Comment: I don't think so: $S^n = \partial B^{n+1}$ and $B^{n+1}$ has trivial homotopy groups while the homotopy groups of $S^n$ are incredibly complicated.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I'll restrict my question to a more specific situation.

Comment: Could you include the definition of a projectively/conformally compactified hyperbolic manifold?

Comment: In the case of the conformal compactification $\bar{M}$  (if it exists) of a hyperbolic manifold $M$, you have homotopy-equivalence $M\to \bar{M}$ and also the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of the pair $(\bar{M}, \partial \bar M)$. You also know that $\pi_i(\partial \bar M)\to 0=\pi_i(\bar{M})$, $i\ne 1$.  I do not  know what the projective compactification is.